# Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:jar is missing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I am developing a code from https://www.dineshonjava.com/microservices-with-spring-boot/. When I update the spring-boot-starter-parent from `1.5.4.RELEASE` to `2.0.4.RELEASE`, build got failed.

Could anyone please guide me what is the issue ?

> Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:jar is missing.

Another error:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - For artifact {org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources:default-resources:process-
     resources) org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:148) at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:123) at 
     org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:157) at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createDependencyArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:
     57) at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createDependencyArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:328) at 
     org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.createArtifacts(MavenMetadataSource.java:503) at
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Eureka registration server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>Camden.SR5</version> -->
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Dependencies were renamed, include Netflix nowadays.

Comment: @Tim - Could you please post corrected maven dependencies? I think something has change majorly post 2.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As indicated in my comment, some starters were renamed: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes

> A number of starters did not follow normal Spring Cloud naming conventions. In Edgware, use of the deprecated starter will log a warning with the name of the new starter to use in its place.

So change:
`spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server`
to `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`.

Comment: Even after renaming, issue still persists.

Comment: I am already using "spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server" but it still has issue

Comment: @FaizanMubasher add this dependency management in pom.xml

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>

Answer (score 12):

```
Add the following in to your pom.xml  

<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    OR

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix to

Answer (score 6):

1º) remove dependency from your pom.xml and save the file;

2º) Go to the STS project >  right click > Spring > Edit Starters > search to **Eureka Discovery Client** and mark checkbok > OK.

This action solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following int the Pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
         <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
 </properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 3):

I also was facing similar problem. Using the below pom.xml helped

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even I got the similar error when I was adding dependency for `hystrix`.

> Error :  Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:jar is missing

It worked after changing netflix `<artifactId>`

```
from: spring-cloud-starter-hystrix 
to:   spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix
```

Comment: Hello Ravikumar, welcome to StackOverflow. I have remove your bold characters formatting because is too agressive and I have formatted your question differently in using back character ` to put text on grey background. I have also used code formatting so that comparaison between incorrect code and correct code in artifactId is immediate. You can see what I have already done in clicking on `edit` button just below your question. I hope that can help your for your next post.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things here.
I was trying to create the Eureka server and I faced a couple of problems.

First things

If you are using `spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server` then change it to `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server`.

The link will give the details of the changes.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Edgware-Release-Notes

I recently created the starter project from https://start.spring.io/ and it has the latest changes in pom.xml

This is how it looks like

```html
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You need to make sure that the eureka server dependency version is correct.
You can make sure by adding `<spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>` in properties tag and `${spring-cloud.version}` in dependencyManagement's version tag

If you do not see the `<dependencyManagement>` tag then add the whole dependency in your pom.xml

```html
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

After setting the version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

the error disappeared. Probably not the best solution for production.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding bellow global version,

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Then the dependency without version tag as bellow,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This may help some.

Answer (score 1):

For all those who still having the error after trying above mentioned troubleshooting, they can add this dependency management in pom.xml, it should work.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers posted above and none of them work. The only bulletproof method which worked for me is to create a demo project at https://start.spring.io/ and choose the dependencies Eureka Discovery Client SPRING, then see the pom.xml of the demo project and compare with your current POM.

The demo pom.xml generated from start.spring.io is posted below, I have included comments to list the code I was missing in my XML and upon including I was able to get the compile it successfully.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
          <!-- Update the Spring version in current POM -->
          <version>2.6.0</version>
          <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
      </parent>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>demo</name>
      <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
      <properties>
          <java.version>11</java.version>
          <!-- Missing, include this -->
          <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0-RC1</spring-cloud.version>
      </properties>
      <dependencies>
          <!-- Missing, include this -->
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
          </dependency>
  
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <!-- Missing, include this -->
      <dependencyManagement>
          <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                  <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                  <type>pom</type>
                  <scope>import</scope>
              </dependency>
          </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
  
      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
      <!-- Missing, include this -->
      <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>spring-milestones</id>
              <name>Spring Milestones</name>
              <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
              <snapshots>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
              </snapshots>
          </repository>
      </repositories>
  
  </project>
```

Please include the differences in your current XML.

Answer (score 0):

I Find the solution by trying two things and both solved the problem, I guess it is the issue with the netflix-eureka server version.

***Method 1:*** Simply Use JDK 11.

***Method 2:*** If you are using JDK 8.
Then add this version tag with version 3.0.0,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

this is though not the best practice
and will give the warning of

```
Overriding managed version 3.1.1 for spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server
```

however, it will remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

adding this in pom.xml after dependencies node worked for me.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
I changed my starter parent version from 3.0.0 to 2.7.3 and cloud version to 2021.0.3

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

   <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after adding spring-cloud-dependencies and the netflix repositories
complete pom.xml as below

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.0
 

com.rh
movie-catalog-service
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
MovieCatalogue
movie catalogue service

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>           
</properties>

<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>               
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>netflix-candidates</id>
        <name>Netflix Candidates</name>
        <url>https://artifactory-oss.prod.netflix.net/artifactory/maven-oss-candidates</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, then the problem is in your maven settings.
Check Maven Settings: Verify that IntelliJ IDEA is using the correct Maven installation and settings. Go to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Build Tools" -> "Maven". Ensure that the "Maven home directory" points to the correct location where Maven is installed on your system. Change to Bundled (Maven 3). The problem will disappear then

Answer (score 0):

I got that same error. My pom like bellow

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.thusitha</groupId>
<artifactId>department-service</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>department-service</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So I have to changed my pom like this.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <!-- Add spring cloud verion --> 
    <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
</dependencies>
<!-- Add dependencyManagement --> 
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

dependencyManagement is just a declaration, and it does not really add a dependency.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Update your pom.xml file as following

```
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

This has solved the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Update

---

> Hoxton.RC1

---

to

---

> Greenwich.RELEASE

*** in pom.xml

Comment: the question snippet does not list Hoxton.RC1